# How do I use SetInterval to update pins on a google map from a database?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a Google map set up and it pulls locations from a database. If I refresh the page it is on it displays all of the pins properly, but I would like it to update every 10 seconds so that new pins will show up as they are added. I have the following code, but it isn't pulling the data in. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
function(){
  var mapsvg = this;
  setInterval(()=>{ 
  mapsvg.database.find() 
  }, 10000);
}
```

```html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code  :

```
function fetch(){
  var mapsvg = this;
  setInterval(()=>{ 
  mapsvg.database.find() 
  }, 1000);
}

fetch();
```

Comment: Please vote the solution and accept it ,as it would help others to get the correct solution . Thanks .